# PayPal payment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I've got an app that has the possibility to do shopping, making the money transaction through paypal. I'm trying now to integrate the paypal stuff into my rails project and as I'm trying to learn how that's done I've downloaded [this sample project](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-ruby) that appears to show a good example of how this stuff is done.

I think I've got everything covered when talking about configuration. That app is now all configured with my paypal credentials.

My problem is that after making any payment, when making the callback, the app throws this error:

```
undefined method `recipientName=' for #<PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::Address:0x007feb13a30ee8>
```

Even with the default configuration I'm having this issue.

Does anyone know what is that about? I guess is something about the gems included in the project that have to do with paypal:

```
# PayPal
gem 'paypal-sdk-core', :git => 'https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-ruby.git'
gem 'paypal-sdk-rest', :git => 'https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby.git'
```

But have any clue about how to fix it. Maybe someone does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Definitely was something about the gem versions. Just updated them and problem solved.

Making this:

```
# PayPal
gem 'paypal-sdk-core', :git => 'https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-ruby.git'
gem 'paypal-sdk-rest', :git => 'https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby.git'
```

Didn't installed the latest version of both gems. I've just took out those git specification and after a  `bundle update` the problem was solved.